understanding random variables ; Marginal densities
I need help in solving this class example. I am quite lost on how to go about it. Any help is very much appreciated.image of the example

Please show your attempt and please tell where you are stuck at.

When you want $f_X(x)$, integrate out $y$. When you want $f_Y(y)$, integrate out $x$.
Hence $$f_X(x)= \int_0^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dy$$ Treat $x$ as a constant and just integrate.
For the second part find $$f_Y(y)= \int_0^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dx$$ in the same way. Hence see that $f_X(x) f_Y(y)\neq f_{XY}(x,y)$
